# How to build tree model in SAS by specifying groups for cross validation

Tags: sas, cross-validation

I'd like to build a tree model with cross-validation. I'd like to assign observations to different cross-validation groups by myself instead of random sampling. I am not sure how SAS can do this. It would be helpful if anybody can share some example SAS code.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Need more details, what tools are you using, E-Miner or Studio, which procs and how do you want to assign the rules? It could be as simple as a data step with some IF statements or could require PROC SURVEYSELECT or not be possible if you're using a CV option within a procedure.

Comment: It is SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M5. I saw HPSLIT procs can do the tree model. Not sure what other options are.

Comment: I have monthly time-series data. And I want to predict forward 3 months. So there are some overlapping periods when running cross-validation. For example, if Jan and Feb are in the training set and March in the testing set, the model might know what is likely to happen when using the training set due to the overlap period. Currently, I am sampling before building the tree model and assign group id for cross-validation. For example, assign Jan, Feb, and Mar as group 1 and Jun and Jul as group 2. Pass the group ID to the tree model function. I implement it in R.

Comment: Do you have ETS (e.g. proc arima, proc ucm, etc.)? You might want to consider using a time-series model rather than a decision tree for forecasting. If you did go that route, a random forest or gradient boosting would likely have bette results.

Comment: What proc are you using? Seems like you will just need to use data steps or SQL to manually partition it as I don't know of a way to partition based on a time field. I think some of the time series procs do that but not the Tree based ones that I know of.

Comment: I use HPSLIT procs.

Comment: You'll need to make your data splits manually, I don't think there's a way to control that in the proc. A data step or SQL will work fine.